# Every solution of a permutation equation?

Tags: permutations

I have the three permutations
$$a=(1\;3\;4\;8),\quad b=(2\;3\;5\;7),\quad c=(4\;3\;2\;8)$$
and I have to find all $x$ satisfying
$$axb=c.$$
I have found one solution (I hope it's good):
$$x=(7\;5\;1\;8\;3\;2)$$
Now my problem is, that the task says I have to find every solution.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Permutations are invertible. So the only solution $x$ to $axb=c$ is $x=a^{-1}cb^{-1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a permutation is a bijective function, and is hence invertible. Therefore we can isolate $x$ by left multiplying each side of the equation by $a^{-1}$ and right-multiplying each side of the equation by $b^{-1}$ to get

So $$axb = c \iff xb = a^{-1} c \iff x = a^{-1} c b^{-1}$$

Now, we need the inverses of $a$, $b$:$$a^{-1} = (8431) = (1843),\quad b^{-1} = (7532) = (2753)$$

Comment: But the task says I have to give all the solutions for x in S8. So there isn't any other solution?

Comment: The solution is unique. The product (composition) of permutation is a permutation, and as such it is uniquely determined by the factors.

Comment: No, it is the only solution. Every step above is if and only if.